# Comparing a list to a a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have two lists. One is simply a list of ids

`ids = [123, 124, 127, 316, 463]`

and the other is a list of tuples of id's and names

`combined = [(123, "Brian"), (124,"Eric"), (222,"Jane")]`

What is the easiest way to do set comparisons on these?  I need to find out two things - ids that exist in the first list that don't appear in the second list, specifically  `127, 316, 463` and vice versa, which would be `(222, "Jane")`.

I am using Python 2.5.

Comment: Why still using Python 2.5?!

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a really out of date version of python? what have you tried?

Comment: My job haha.  As though this was a personal choice.  Right now the only way I can see doing it is for loops.  Which I can do.  I just thought there was a nicer way.

Comment: My first thought is that combined should be a dict, and then you could use combined.keys(), and then you have two lists.

Comment: I will fax you the answer after the Spice Girls concert

Comment: Very helpful, thanks @wim!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should upgrade to Python 2.7 at the very least, if something doesn't prevent you from doing so.

You can compare `ids` to the first element of each list in `combined` if you want to compare the numbers:

```
ids = [123, 124, 127, 316, 463]
combined = [(123, "Brian"), (124,"Eric"), (222,"Jane")]
combined_first = [x[0] for x in combined]
```

Comment: I wish I could upgrade.  Sadly I cannot.  But ok I can just do that make the two lists and go from there I suppose.

Comment: The combined_first line provides a good answer. Instead of lists, I would generate sets, and the next part of OP is answered by the set minus operator. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-operations-union-intersection-difference-symmetric-difference/ (tested on 2.7.13)

Comment: Which commentary should I delete?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects sorry meant to link official docs the first time.