# compare list items in LIST A to each first element in a list of tuples LIST B

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

My question is almost similar to this one - [Comparing a list to a a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836845/comparing-a-list-to-a-a-list-of-tuples) but i am looking for a solution to just comparing .....

I have

ListA = `[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]`
ListB = `[(1, 'Poor'), (2, 'Average'), (3, 'Excellent')]` List of tuples.

In the end i want to generate a new List of tuples - LISTC containing all elements in LIST A like this

`[(2, 'Average'), (1,'Poor'), ( 1, 'Poor') , (1 ,'Poor') , (1, 'Poor')]`

I have tried this -

```
first_tuple_elements = [element[0] for element in LISTB]
final_list_of_tuples = ()
for i in LISTA:
    for i in first_tuple_elements:
        final_list_of_tuples = [(i, element[1]) for element in LISTB]

print(final_list_of_tuples)
```

The above is not giving me what i want , kindly assist

LISTB is a resultset from a database query and 
LISTA is the computed resultset which i then need to compare with items in LISTB so i can generate

LISTC `[(2, 'Average'), (1,'Poor'), ( 1, 'Poor') , (1 ,'Poor') , (1, 'Poor')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `ListB` to dictionary first:

```
ListA = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
ListB = [(1, 'Poor'), (2, 'Average'), (3, 'Excellent')]

d = dict(ListB)
ListC = [(v, d[v]) for v in ListA]

print(ListC)
```

Prints:

```
[(2, 'Average'), (1, 'Poor'), (1, 'Poor'), (1, 'Poor'), (1, 'Poor')]
```

Comment: using a dictionary is a better way of doing this.

Comment: @sage07 i will try to do a performance test on both answers to see which one is faster. Doesnt changing to a dictionary affect perfomance if you can do it while its a list of tuples

Comment: may be, this can only be revealed after the performance test.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ListA = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
ListB = [(1, 'Poor'), (2, 'Average'), (3, 'Excellent')]
ListC = []
for i in ListA:
    for j in ListB:
        if i == j[0]:
            ListC.append((i, j[1]))

print(ListC)
```

**output**

```
[(2, 'Average'), (1, 'Poor'), (1, 'Poor'), (1, 'Poor'), (1, 'Poor')]
```